# Configuring Elasticsearch

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, sonarqube

I'm part way through adoption of sonarqube which has hit an intermittent issue relating to the Elasticsearch instance it relies on.  To resolve this I believe I need to modify an Elasticsearch config value.

In the `\conf\sonar.properties` settings file I have set

`sonar.search.port=9200`

which gives me the following when I try to access in a browser.

[image]

Great so I just need to construct the right request in powershell?

`Invoke-WebRequest 'localhost:9200'` -Method 'GET'  **URI prefix not recognised**
`Invoke-WebRequest 'http://localhost:9200/' -Method 'GET'`  **Protocol Violation**
`Invoke-WebRequest 'localhost:9200' -Method 'XGET'`  **Cannot convert value "XGET" to type**
`Invoke-WebRequest 'http://localhost:9200/_all/settings' -Method 'GET'` **Protocol Violation**

If I change the Elasticsearch config directly it gets regenerated (as part of the sonar startup perhaps) so I think any config must be done this way.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't underdstand what's ur issue?  is your elasticsearch is running on 9200 port?

Comment: I guess it must be since I get that response on localhost:9200, prior to me changing the setting it was page not found

Comment: Ok, so what the issue now?

Comment: I want to be able to modify an elasticsearch setting but all the requests to the API fail

Comment: r u using curl or postman ? how you are modifying elasticsearch setting, and what exactly you want to modify?

Comment: if you want you can simply modify most of them using rest api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: That's what I'm attempting to do.  I'm using powershell.  I need to change the `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark` levels

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212406/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-m-edmondson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sonar documentation is really lacking.  The correct sonar setting for the port is:

```
sonar.search.httpPort=9200
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your elasticsearch instance is up and running OR its setup to use another port other than 9200 for http. By default, when you access ES via browser, you should have at least have seen a response like the one below (if using Chrome/Firefox). If you using IE, it should have prompted to save this response as JSON.

```
{
  "name" : "ESPOC-NODE1",
  "cluster_name" : "ESPOC",
  "cluster_uuid" : "oZSfvTqmQY-ASngFlxp56A",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "b2f0c09",
    "build_date" : "2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So first get your ES working. Then you can move on to your SONAR setup.